# Como faço para o evento MenuIten.Click ser executado em um laço if? Delphi

Tags: delphi, if, login, menu, submenu

Estou montando a parte do login do meu sistema, só que estou enfrentando um grande problema. O meu botão cancelar da tela de login ele precisa receber duas funcionalidades. A primeira é que ser for clicado antes da tela principal do sistema for aberta a aplicação é toda terminada. Caso se a tela principal já esteja aberta é para fazer a segunda funcionalidade que seria o cancelamento da troca de usuário em tempo de execução ! Ou seja, o cancelamento do logout, a troca de usuário cancelada. Porem para que a lógica que eu estou usando funcione, tem que ser passada por um if, so que o click do logout é um ItemMenu de um MainMenu.
Se eu usar assim

```
if FrmPrincipal.Logout1.Click = True then
```

Ele acusa erro de incompatible type
Se eu usu dessa outra maneira

```
if FrmPrincipal.Logout1.OnClick
```

Ele da erro e nem roda. É isso que queria saber... como faço para um ItemMenu seja executado em um laço if.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu fosse você, controlaria com uma variável privada alimentando no onCreate do principal, assim ele abriria o Login e no onCreate do Login alimentava a variável com False, no onShow do principal verifico se é para fazer login ou não, olhando a variável. Da seguinte maneira:

**onCreate** Principal:

```
bLogin := False;
fmLogin := TfmLogin.Create(Self); 
try
  fmLogin.ShowModal;
  bLogin := fmLogin.OKLogin;
finally
   FreeAndNil(fmLogin);
end;
```

**onCreate** Login:

```
bOKLogin := False
```

**onShow** Principal:

```
if bLogin then
begin
  ...
end
else
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Mas partindo da sua lógica, você pode chamar o evento OnClick do Logout não precisando verificar se clicou ou não.

```
   FrmPrincipal.Logout1.OnClick(Sender)
```

Podes também controlar com um Checked no MenuItem, no MenuItem tem uma propriedade com AutoCheck, marcando essa propriedade ele vai controlar o check no menuItem, com isso podes verificar se está checado ou não na hora que ele clica no MenuItem.

```
 if testecheck.Checked then
     ShowMessage('teste');
```

Comment: Esse código que me passou continuou dando o mesmo erro. Então a tela de Login chamo ela no onCreate do Principal. Eu não consegui entender direito o que você falou na parte do onShow.

Comment: @AlisonPaulo, se você chamar a tela do Login no onCreate do principal, com um showmodal, ele vai fica esperando o retorno da tela do Login, pois é um Showmodal, no onCreate do Login poderias colocar uma variável privada como false, se ele fechar a tela do login, vai voltar para a tela do onCreate do principal você poderia alimentar em uma variável o retorno do Login. Logo depois do OnCreate do Principal ele cai no onShow, nessa parte você verifica se é para fazer login ou não. Não sei se fui claro.

Comment: Interessante não tinha pensado desse jeito, vou implementar agora, deixa eu so perguntar uma coisa, o que seria o OKLogin uma variável? Desculpa a pergunta mas sou programador junior aprendendo ainda hehe. a variável blogin seria do tipo tform?

Comment: As duas variáveis são do tipo Boolean, uma você declara no principal e a outra no Login, quando você entra no onCrete do Login você já declara ela como False, pois se você sair da tela do Login ela já está como falso, então não vai acontecer evento nenhum e quando voltar para o onCreate do Principal você alimenta a variável booleana do principal com a variavel booleana do Login.

Comment: @AlisonPaulo, conseguiu resolver o problema?... se conseguiu poderia marcar a resposta para ajudar os outros membros do fórum.

Comment: Assim, pelo que testei dependendo de como está desenvolvendo funciona sim, para mim não deu certo porque vai influencia diretamente na restrições dos usuários logados. Como tem um Free ele vai limpar todas a informações do usuário logado. E as restrições tem ligação com o id do usuário logado, dando aquele freeandnil limpa o id ai o sistema fica sem as restrições, mas pelo que testei daria certo sim, pra mim infelizmente não deu, mas agradeço muito sua ajuda, graças a isso encontrei uma nova lógica para login em sistemas delphi.

Comment: @AlisonPaulo se resolveu para você, tem como marcar a resposta, assim serve para outros usuários. Obrigado